# Rails 4 - Displaying only data associated with a specific user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a question/answer app.  The questions are static and provided, not user generated.  The data is being accessed via a nested relationship.

On the individual user view I want to show a list of the questions that the user has answer and its associated answer.  Like this:

Question 1
User 1 answer

At this point, I am showing each question, but all of the answers are showing, not just those of the specific user.  Like this:

Question 1
User 1 answer
User 2 answer

Here is the code in my show.view. I have also tried it without the "if answer.user" line and got the same result.

```
<% @user.questions.uniq.each do |question| %>
  <h3><div class="answer"><%= question.question %> </div></h3>
    <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
    <% if answer.user = current_user %>
      <div class="answer"><%= answer.answer %> <%= answer.created_at.strftime("(%Y)") %></div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My models:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  has_many :users, through: :answers
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  has_many :questions, through: :answers
end
```

My Routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :answers
end
```

I'm happy to provide any other code that would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign current_user to answer.user, you want test equality change with this line

```
if answer.user == current_user
```

Comment: jeez!  I can't believe I missed that!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Actually i prefer to treat it on a different level, I believe this should work too

```
<% @user.questions.uniq.each do |question| %>
  <h3><div class="answer"><%= question.question %> </div></h3>
  <% question.answers.where(user: @user).each do |answer| %>
    <div class="answer"><%= answer.answer %> <%= answer.created_at.strftime("(%Y)") %></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```